# Firestore Fetching Multiple Documents Best Practice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I need 5 distinct documents from a Firestore collection. I don't need to query Firestore at all - I already have the document ID's. What is the best practice for fetching them?

I am currently using `Promise.all` to fetch them in parallel but it *seems* like a single call to Firestore would be even better in terms of network and compute overhead? However, I can't find a batch read method for the web SDK. Is `Promise.all` the best practice for fetching several documents at once?

Comment: This was my problem too. My current best guess is that I create an "index" array in the document where this subcollection belongs. That will contain only the ids of the subcollection. And I am updating it when I add or remove document to/from the related subcollection. One can add or remove elements without updating the whole array, but the size limitation related to the document that that contains it is szill there.

Comment: @ZorgoZ after thinking about it, I posted the following answer to the duplicate question: ...avoid `Promise.all` unless you can't. Let the individual reads resolve independently so as to allow the client to resolve it's components ASAP.

Comment: @RonRoyson Just keep in mind that each document touched (even if only its id is fetched) counts as a read operation!